# How to covert Image to byte[] or bitmap in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap

Can someone help me to solve a problem in Android Studio? I am creating an app in which I have a photo in JPEG format(Comming from the camera, not from file) and I want to convert it to bitmap.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to convert image to byte[]. Like this:

```
public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
     return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Here image variable is a JPEG file/image.

```
        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
```